# DataGrid for Android

Tags: java, android, datagrid

Hello i want to build an Android application to handle my budget. I have build an budget-app before but that was in WPF and with C#. In WPF there is something called DataGrid that looks something like this

https://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples/datasetgrid.png
(I am not allowed to post images)

And i was wondering if there was something like this in Android, that could display a table of information to the user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Grid View](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

> GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional,
>   scrollable grid. The grid items are automatically inserted to the
>   layout using a ListAdapter.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // i used this array list for quick purpose
    // better way to use data models

    private String[][] gradingData = new String[][]{
            {"S.N", "Range", "Grading", "Description", "GP"},
            {"1", "90-100", "A+", "Outstanding", "4.0"},
            {"2", "80-90", "A", "Excellent", "3.6"},
            {"3", "70-80", "B+", "Very Good", "3.2"},
            {"4", "60-70", "B", "Good", "2.8"},
            {"5", "50-60", "C", "Average", "2.4"},
            {"6", "Below 50", "D", "Below Average", "2.0"},
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
        parentLayout.addView(createTableLayout(7, 5));
    }

    private TableLayout createTableLayout(int rowCount, int columnCount) {
        // 1) Create a tableLayout and its params
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        //  tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        // 2) create tableRow params
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        tableRowParams.weight = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            // 3) create tableRow
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            // tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                // 4) create textView
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textview_border));
                textView.setText(gradingData[i][j]);
                if (i == 0) {
                    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#aeaeae"));
                }
                tableRow.addView(textView, tableRowParams);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow, tableLayoutParams);
        }

        return tableLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: worked for me, at the time you defined data we can call respective API to load data for the table

Answer (score 1):

As Leuteris said you can use Grid View.

But you should try to think about new design of your UI - use ideas from desktop clients in mobile application is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`. It is very easy to implement.